# Import web data into google sheet using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was using ImportXML to scrape dates however, I have since learned ImportXML has a cap and I've switched to writing my own script. Currently the script I've pieced together "loads" a completely empty cell, as seen here [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MKJv9XzFrzNkQyjTY2XPA2zPo0vJXwOpvA4uz6twiqY/edit?usp=sharing) the script is pasted below. I'm not very experienced writing scripts and having problems identifying what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```js
function IDATE(id) 
{
  const url = "https://www.buyma.com/item/" + id;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const s = response.getContentText();

  var match = /[@id='s_yukodate']/.exec(s);
  if (match != null) 
  {
    date = match[1];
  }

  return [date];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the script is supposed to do, nor what the script is failing to do.  It would also be helpful to give an example of the data at the buymy URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

First, setup the sheet in the following format for the script to work -

[image: before]

Then, use the following code in the script editor -

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = values[0];
  var idIndex = header.indexOf('ID');
  var dateIndex = header.indexOf('Date');
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var id = values[i][idIndex];
    var date = IDATE(id);
    ss.getRange(i+1, dateIndex+1).setValue(date);
  }
}

function IDATE(id) {
  const url = "https://www.buyma.com/item/" + id;
  Logger.log(url);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const s = response.getContentText();
  var match = /s_yukodate[\s\S]*?<dd>(\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d).*<\/dd>/.exec(s);
  if (match != null) {
    var date = match[1];
    return date;
  }
}
```

You'll accordingly see an output that looks like this -

[image: after]

Obviously, this script is highly contingent on the regex being used -

`s_yukodate[\s\S]*?<dd>(\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d).*<\/dd>`

Please feel free to modify that, as required. Hope this helps!